# Word VSTO addin - Click event not firing?

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I am writing my first VSTO AddIn for Word, I have managed to add a button to the "Track Changes" context menu, but I can not get it to call my click handler.I can see the button there, but clicking it does nothing - I never get into `ButtonClick` and there are no exceptions. I have tried setting `Enabled` to true, `Visible` to true, but to no avail.

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
   {
      Word.Application application;
      string insertText = "INSERT!!";
      Office.CommandBarButton acceptButton;
      Office.CommandBar commandBar;

      private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
      {
         application = this.Application;
         application.WindowBeforeRightClick +=
             new Word.ApplicationEvents4_WindowBeforeRightClickEventHandler(application_WindowBeforeRightClick);         

         application.DocumentOpen += 
             new Word.ApplicationEvents4_DocumentOpenEventHandler(WorkWithDocument);

         ((Word.ApplicationEvents4_Event)this.Application).NewDocument +=
             new Word.ApplicationEvents4_NewDocumentEventHandler(WorkWithDocument);

      }

      private void WorkWithDocument(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document Doc)
      {
         try
         {
            application.CustomizationContext = application.ActiveDocument;
            commandBar = application.CommandBars["Track Changes"];
            acceptButton = (Office.CommandBarButton)commandBar.Controls.Add(
                Office.MsoControlType.msoControlButton);
            acceptButton.accName = insertText;
            acceptButton.Caption = insertText;              
            acceptButton.Click += new Office._CommandBarButtonEvents_ClickEventHandler(ButtonClick);
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
            Debug.Print(ex.StackTrace);

            // Handle exception if for some reason the document is not available.
         }
      }

      // Handles the event when a button on the new toolbar is clicked. 
      private void ButtonClick(Office.CommandBarButton ctrl, ref bool cancel)
      {
         try
         {
            Debug.Print("You clicked: " + ctrl.Caption);
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
            Debug.Print(ex.Message);
         }
      }

...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command bars were deprecated. Starting from Word 2007 the Ribbon UI (aka Fluent UI) is used instead. Read more about the Fluent UI in the following articles:

- [Customizing Context Menus in Office 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee691832(v=office.14).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Damn outdated tutorials.